# How to generate a random, non-guessable string for the "state" parameter in OAuth using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm building a simple website and want to implement OAuth for authentication.

I've read that including a "state" parameter in the authorization request is necessary to prevent CSRF attacks. However, I'm not sure if my implementation to achieve protection from CSRF attack using the state parameter is correct.

To prevent CSRF attacks, I'm considering the following approach:

1. Generate a random string.
2. Encrypt the string and store it in an httpOnly cookie so that I can retrieve it later.
3. Hash the string and provide it in the front end to pass the hash value to the authorization server as a state.
4. When the authorization server passes the "state" parameter back to the callback URL, compare the hashed value to the original string retrieved from the cookie.

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you're authenticating in the frontend, just keep the value in the frontend (session storage). You don't need to encrypt or hash.

Comment: @Evert I'm not authenticating in the frontend. I have a server, and the authorization server redirects the user back to the callback url with the state param and authorization code which can be stollen because of malicious browser extension which can lead to CSRF attack because there will be no way to confirm if the user is legit if the state is in plain text. Here is how to implement login flow using facebook oauth - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/

Comment: 1. If you have a malicious extension, you have way bigger problems. The state parameter does little to protect you. The `code` parameter would be able to get leaked anyway and that's the main way someone would still the session. The `state` is irrelevant. 2) If your server does the authorization flow, there's no need to put the state parameter in a cookie, Just keep it on the server.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/attack-protection/state-parameters

Comment: @Evert I found myself somewhat confused about CSRF. CSRF tokens are intended to serve a different purpose than the one I was trying to solve. Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense, good luck! It's a complex subject =)